# Prove if $\sum_ja_{ij}Aj$ commute with each other, then $A_j$ commute with each othe

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $(a_{ij})$is a $n\times n$ invertible matrix, and $A_1,\cdots A_n$ are linear transformations on the same vector space, how to prove if $\sum_ja_{ij}A_j$ commute with each other, then $A_j$ commute with each other?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the source of this problem?

Comment: @AhmedHussein Halmos finite dimensional vector space,section of determinant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U=[a_{ij}]$ and $B_i=\sum_j a_{ij}A_j$; then $[B_1,\cdots,B_n]^T=U[A_1,\cdots,A_n]^T$ and $U^{-1}[B_1,\cdots,B_n]^T=[A_1,\cdots,A_n]^T$. Thus $span(B_1,\cdots,B_n)=span(A_1,\cdots,A_n)$. Finally the $(B_i)_i$ pairwise commute IFF the $(A_i)_i$ pairwise commute.